# Why am I getting a No Reverse Match Error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

HI working on a new site using Django. can't seem to figure this bug out. First the intended site will be structured as;

Home page - Showing different languages with links to countries you can learn those languages in.
Click on a country on home page -> Country page
Country page will list all fo the schools that teach that language in that country.
Click on a school on country page -> School page.

I figured out this line of code in the Country page is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix it

```
<a href="{% url 'schools' schools.id %}">
    <div class="left"><h4>Test Link</h4></div>
</a>
```

This is the error I get in the browser

```
NoReverseMatch at /5/ Reverse for 'schools' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<country_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<schools_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Code from the project:
Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Languages(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ManyToManyField('Country', blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language

class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country_image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    country_city = models.ManyToManyField('City', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    city_schools_in = models.ManyToManyField('Schools', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name

class Schools(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    school_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    school_country = models.ManyToManyField('Country', blank=True)
    school_city = models.ManyToManyField('City', blank=True)
    school_description = models.TextField()
    school_accreditations = models.ManyToManyField('Accreditations', blank=True)
    school_lpw = models.IntegerField()
    school_cs = models.IntegerField()
    school_course = models.ManyToManyField('CoursePrices', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

class Accreditations(models.Model):
    accreditation_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.accreditation_name

class CoursePrices(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    lessons_per_week = models.IntegerField()
    class_size = models.IntegerField()
    weekly_price =  models.IntegerField()
    language_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_title
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

from .models import Schools, CoursePrices, Languages, Country, City


def home(request):
    languages = Languages.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'languages': languages,
    })

def country(request, country_id):
    try:
        country = Country.objects.get(id=country_id)
    except Languages.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Language not found')
    return render(request, 'country.html', {
        'country': country,
    })

def schools(request, country_id, schools_id):
    try:
        schools = Schools.objects.get(id=schools_id)
    except Schools.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('school not found')
    return render(request, 'schools.html', {
        'schools': schools,
    })
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from schools import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<int:country_id>/', views.country, name='country'),
    path('<int:country_id>/<int:schools_id>/', views.schools, name='schools'),
]
```

Project structure screenshot

[image: Project structure screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also please forgive any mistakes in posting or coding, still very new to coding and stack overflow / life in general :)

Answer (score 1):

Your path named `schools` requires two arguments, you only passed one, so it failed to match any route.

Your comment on Rafael's answer that it is still not matching the path, even with two arguments provided, is because of the order of the paths in your `urls.py` file.

Django will go through the list of paths in order, and because a path with the single parameter `country_id` is found first it tries that but fails because you have a second parameter.

To fix that change the order of your paths

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    # next two lines have been swapped. 
    path('<int:country_id>/<int:schools_id>/', views.schools, name='schools'),
    path('<int:country_id>/', views.country, name='country'),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like you were 9 seconds before me xD Why are people always faster than me? :( xD

Comment: @Rafael - No worries. I'm usually the one being surprised by how fast people answer questions here :D

Comment: @Rafael Don't worry about more developed answers taking longer to post. It's better to take the time to make a good answer than it is to rush one out.

Comment: Hi thank you for the update @Tony I have tried the suggestion you posted (I'm assuming the name='schools'), was intended for the end of the line above?). I still can't seem to get it to work. I feel like it could be an issue with how I have implemented the views in that I am not passing the correct school ID

Comment: @Tony this was the command line when I tried implementing you suggestion 
/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'schools' with keyword arguments '{'country_id': 6, 'schools_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<country_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<schools_id>[0-9]+)/$']
[07/Feb/2021 20:00:15] "GET /6/ HTTP/1.1" 500 191480

Comment: @SkyFall It looks like there's a problem with your Django project setup. Could you add a screenshot of your folder structure to your question? That may help in finding the problem.

Comment: @Rafael Hi thanks for the reply. I have added the screenshot

Comment: @SkyFall thanks! While looking at your screenshot I just realized something in your error: `'('',)'` do not look like integers. Are you sure the schools.id and country.id template variables exist and are integers?

Answer (score 1):

The 'schools' url needs two (2) arguments. You only pass one (1). In this case: schools.id

Django only finds a reverse match if you pass the correct amount of arguments. In this case, you should pass a country id AND a school id.

E.g. `{% url 'schools' country_id=country.id schools_id=schools.id %}` if you also have a country variable.

EDIT: `'('',)'` in your error message don't really look like integers. Are you sure the template variables exists and are integers?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. that makes sense, I've copied and pasted your suggestion. still getting an error 

NoReverseMatch at /6/
Reverse for 'schools' with keyword arguments '{'country_id': 6, 'schools_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<country_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<schools_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: @SkyFall - I've added to my answer to solve the problem you have with the parameters.